# Pytest: How to test a function that contains a global variable?

Tags: python, testing, mocking, pytest, pytest-django

I am using `redis` in the following way:

```
from redis import Redis

redis_client = Redis()

def get_datetime_from_redis(key):

    start_time = redis_client.get(key)
    start_time = datetime.strptime(datetime_as_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    duration = (datetime.now() - start_time).total_seconds()
    return duration
```

I'd like to test the function in the following way:

```
import pytest
from core.utils import get_datetime_from_redis
from unittest.mock import Mock
from datetime import datetime


def test_get_datetime_from_redis(monkeypatch):
    
    mock_redis = Mock()
    mock_redis.get.return_value = datetime(2022, 1, 26)
    monkeypatch.setattr('core.utils.Redis', mock_redis)

    get_datetime_from_redis('foo')
    
    mock_redis.get.assert_called_once()
```

But the issue is that by the time that `monkeypatch.setattr('core.utils.Redis', mock_redis)` is run, `redis_client` is already instantiated, so I'm not mocking the correct version.

How do I address these kinds of tests?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it is a global variable should not be an issue : monckeypatch can be apply on every scope and even existing instances.

The issue here is the way you are using the monckeypatch fixture.

Since the function is consuming `redis_clent` variable from the `core.utils` module, the `monckeypatch` fixture should **mock it**, instead of the Redis class itself.

So :

```py
import pytest
from core.utils import redis_client
from core.utils import get_datetime_from_redis
from datetime import datetime


def test_get_datetime_from_redis(monkeypatch):
    redis_get_called = []

    # define mock function
    def mock_redis_get(self, k, default=None) :
        get_called.append(1) # Add to call count
        return datetime(2022, 1, 26)
    
    # patch redis_client variable
    monkeypatch.setattr(redis_client, 'get', mock_redis_get)

    # act  
    get_datetime_from_redis('foo')

    # assert
    assert len(redis_get_called) == 1
```

Now just pay attention to the signature of the [Redis`get` method](https://github.com/redis/redis-py/blob/24cdd70761c7c275d5010f628f83d919bf35fc90/redis/client.py#L67) :

In monckeypatch , it is a good idea to have the same signature than the mocked function... this is why the mock function here has also a `self`, `k` (and not `key`), and a `default` parameters (I think that this last one can be ignored since it is an optional parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will solve entirely the problem but you should design your tests to have a `fixture` in charge of managing the creation of the mocked redis (`mock_redis`). By encapsulating this code in a fixture you will be able to manage when the `fixture` is created (once per session, per module, per function) and to gather all this code at a single location.
[Here](https://pytest-mock-resources.readthedocs.io/en/latest/redis.html) is a good example on how to do that.

Second point is on the way you  instantiate `redis_client` client in your code. Since it's not done in a method or in a class, `redis_client` is created as soon as the module is imported. You should also consider deferring the instantiation by putting it in a method or class you can call when needed.